# Can we run karate scripts across all the environment set in karate-config.js file in one shot

Tags: karate

I have below karate-config.js file:
https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-configjs

Now, I wish to run both the environments stage & e2e together through eclipse IDE or command prompt and wish to get the results as per the environment or group by the environment.
Is that possible? I went through karate doc. https://github.com/intuit/karate but I can not see the feature I am looking for. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is what tags are designed for: https://github.com/intuit/karate#cucumber-tags - and it sounds like you have not designed your tests correctly.

You can always run for 2 environments by running the parallel runner 2 times. But the reports will be over-written unless you use different output directories.