# How to launch tests in multiple environments with karate framework?

Tags: testing, karate

I created a runner to run all the UI tests for my application like this. The problem is that when I run this runner, all the tests run on a single environment (local, for example).
I'd like the tests to run on another environment as well (env recipe).

So I'd like to be able to see how the tests ran in each environment in the generated test report.
Here's my code:

public class AllTestsRunner {

```
@Test
void allTestUI() {
    List<String> tags = Arrays.asList("~@ignore");
    List<String> features = Arrays.asList("classpath:ui");
    String karateOutputPath = "target/surefire-reports";
    Results results = Runner.path(features)
            .tags(tags)
            .outputCucumberJson(true)
            .reportDir(karateOutputPath).parallel(1);
    generateReport(karateOutputPath);
    assertTrue(results.getFailCount() == 0, results.getErrorMessages());
}


public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
    Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[]{"json"}, true);
    List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList<>(jsonFiles.size());
    jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "Full Ace");
    ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
    reportBuilder.generateReports();
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: if you want to aggregate multiple environments into one report that may not be possible directly. karate should technically be able to run two `Runner` `Suite`s in parallel. you should consider contributing code to karate. some hints here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53393370/143475 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60387907/143475